# PHP app static values in files or database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a api which will be served through a LEMP stack.

There are some settings variables that I need to set. It could for instance be a variable telling if the system is in maintenance mode and let the code behave accordingly. This variable is read often (every request) but not changed very often.

What would be considered as best practice? Storing these settings variables in a database (MySQL in this case) or in actual files? Is there a third way I haven't thought of?

Comment: Querying a database for application-wide config options was more common in the PHP4 era. If it doesn't change hourly, then it doesn't often make sense.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read further on the other answer!